# In my web app, when should I choose to make API calls, over storing data locally?

Tags: reactjs, redux, web-applications, react-redux

### Context:

I am working on a small "google drive" web app. I store users and their objects. Some features are premium if you buy a subscription. Recently, I started using redux because I tired of "waterfalling" things like `uid` from the top, to the bottom of the component tree through props.

### The Problem:

My beginner-common-sense says "I should fetch subscription-status **once**, store it locally, and never make another subscription-status fetch again". BUT I have since run into situations where, say, the user upgrades their subscription, or it expires, and **the source of truth has changed, but the local state has not.**

Basically, I have a specific case where I could fetch user-state from the API EVERYTIME I load a specific component (like the landing page) OR I can fetch it once, and just be really careful about keeping local state up-to-date.

My worst fear is having out-of-sync state, like a user not having access to features they just bought.

### The Question

In general, when should I:

- fetch state straight from the source of truth, at the cost of redundant calls and wait time

versus

- store as much state locally as possible, at the cost of added complexity when trying to keep changing state up-to-date?

Rules of Thumb, best practices, any advice is welcome!

Comment: For not-too-much data (and license is definitely an example for not-too-much-data :) it sounds like a good idea to save the state locally. but this will not work if the user has the app running on another device... If this is not a concern here, then saving API calls is a good idea. Unless you are talking about significant amounts of data.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should store the subscription status locally as well, and if an user upgrades, just make sure that if the upgrade payment (or other criterion) was successful, refresh the subscription status.

Why this would be feasible is because an user is not expected to upgrade or modify their subscription status frequently.